# Remove dead icons from Start menu in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have uninstalled some preinstalled bloatware from Microsoft windows 10 to speed up my computer but after I did that some Microsoft store apps that are already uninstalled were listed in the start menu and these apps did not have any icon. Can someone please tell me how to remove them?

[image: Here is the first image]

[image: Here is the second image]

[image: Here is another image]